# Show a button if TranslateX is higher than 0

Tags: javascript

```js
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var right = document.getElementById("right");
right.addEventListener("click", moveRight);


const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
var imageX = 0;
function moveRight(e) {
   imageX += -vw;
   image.style.position = "relative";
   image.style.transform = "translateX(" + imageX + "px)";
   e.preventDefault();
}

var left = document.getElementById("left");
left.addEventListener("click", moveLeft);

function moveLeft(e) {
    imageX += vw;
    image.style.position = "relative";
    image.style.transform = "translateX(" + imageX + "px)";
    e.preventDefault();
}

function getTranslateX(element) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
    const matrix = new DOMMatrixReadOnly(style.transform);
    const value = matrix.m41;
    return {
        value
    }
}

if(getTranslateX(image) === 0) {
    document.getElementById("left").style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
    document.getElementById("left").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
/*----- Slideshow -----*/

.slideshow {
    width:5000px;
    height:100%;
}

.image {
    width:4096px;
    background:url(https://i.imgur.com/QzQPleZ.jpeg) no-repeat;
    height:1080px;
    transition:2s;
}

.buttons {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:30px;
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
        <div class="buttons" id="buttons">
        <a id="left">Left</a>
        <a id="right">Right</a>
        </div>
        <div class="image" id="image">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to hide a button if the translateX is 0 and if is higher than 0 show the button

This is my code

```js
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var right = document.getElementById("right");
right.addEventListener("click", moveRight);


const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
var imageX = 0;
function moveRight(e) {
   imageX += -vw;
   image.style.position = "relative";
   image.style.transform = "translateX(" + imageX + "px)";
   e.preventDefault();
}

var left = document.getElementById("left");
left.addEventListener("click", moveLeft);

function moveLeft(e) {
    imageX += vw;
    image.style.position = "relative";
    image.style.transform = "translateX(" + imageX + "px)";
    e.preventDefault();
}

function getTranslateX(element) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
    const matrix = new DOMMatrixReadOnly(style.transform);
    const value = matrix.m41;
    return {
        value
    }
}

if(getTranslateX(image) === 0) {
    document.getElementById("left").style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
    document.getElementById("left").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Can I get any help please? I am really stuck in this, I think is mostly my Javascript code because I am newbie in Javascript and I am trying to learn more.

So the problem is the next one

I have a translateX that can go to the right and to the left. I want if Translate X is equal to zero so dont show left button and If TranslateX is more than zero show LEFT Button

I have this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: xPosition is not defined

Comment: there's not enough code to understand the situation

Comment: Sorry I just edited. Thanks for comment

Comment: If you click Run code snippet, there are errors, most likely because no HTML was provided for the JavaScript to act on. In any case, since you're setting the value of translateX, why not just store it in a more easily available attribute, like `data-x`?

Comment: Your HTML is missing Mate @ValeriaAcevedo Add that

Comment: Ready! I just added my HTML and CSS too

Comment: @HereticMonkey how can I do that? Can you please help me out I am newbie in Javascript